# Pre-fill input type date

Tags: angularjs, input, datepicker

I am using ng-repeat to iterate over an object. This object has various properties out of which one is date. I want to show user the date which is already present in the object. And also give the user an ability to change the date. That's why I am using input type date.

Here is that part of code -

```
<input type="date" id="{{field.label}}"
       ng-model="dealsPageCtlrScope.selectedDeal[field.xmlKey]"
       value="{{dealsPageCtlrScope.selectedDeal[field.xmlKey]}}">
```

But this does't pre-fills the date. Current format of the date in the object is 08/14/2014 12:36:05. Please let me know what all ways I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the date in following format "2013-01-08". For more you can refer http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.value

Comment: Using a function to format the date in this way and assigning it to the model value your trying to populate works.